# codeigniter4 4.2.1 does not connect to sqlserver database

Tags: php, sql-server, codeigniter-4

update to the latest version of codeigniter 4 the 4.2.1 but it does not connect me to the database but I try with the previous version that I made as a backup the 4.1.9 and it works perfect I get an error when connecting tcp
I connect as follows and it worked fine

```
 public $local = [
    'DSN' => '',
    'hostname' => '11.11.22.3\SQLEXPRESS',
    'username' => 'ROOT',
    'password' => 'EJEMPLO',
    'database' => 'EJEMPLO',
    'DBDriver' => 'sqlsrv',
    'DBPrefix' => '',
    'pConnect' => false,
    'DBDebug' => (ENVIRONMENT !== 'production'),
    'charset' => 'utf8',
    'DBCollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
    'swapPre' => '',
    'encrypt' => false,
    'compress' => false,
    'strictOn' => false,
    'failover' => [],
    'port' => 1200,
];
```

They are fictitious data since with the real thing I can connect up to 4.1.9

error

Unable to connect to the database.
Main connection [sqlsrv]: TCP Provider: No se puede establecer una conexión ya que el equipo de destino denegó expresamente dicha conexión.

Login timeout expired
A network-related or instance-specific error has occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. Server is not found or not accessible. Check if instance name is correct and if SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. For more information see SQL Server Books Online.

Comment: _I get an error when connecting_ Please [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/72653730/edit) your question to include the full and complete error message - as text, not screen shot(s).

Comment: Aside... `ROOT` is not a normal account name on Microsoft SQL Server. Are you actually attempting to connect to a MySQL or MariaDB server, or did you  mean to use `sa` here (which is bad for other reasons, including security)?

Comment: They are data that I invented right now since the true ones I am not going to put

Answer (score 0):

For me, I copy the connection file of the 4.1.9 version to 4.2.1 and it works.

[image: File List]

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).